# Убрать метатег generator

Tags: cms, drupal, seo

Решил я сделать небольшой проектик на новом Drupal 8 и тут значит возник небольшой вопрос. Решение не нашол. Нужно как то избавиться от метатега generator, в седьмом друпале делал подобное модулем metatag, а на восьмерке или этот модуль еще сырой или я не могу с ним разобраться, но метатег я так и не убрал. Как можно его все таки убрать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *Drupal 8* эту задачу решит использование [hook_page_attachments_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8), который служит для удаления или изменения библиотек, мета-тегов, тегов `link` и HTTP-заголовков. Хук вызывается сразу после вызова [hook_page_attachments()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8) и перед рендером страницы.

Рассмотрим пример удаления мета-тегов `Generator`, `MobileOptimized` и `HandheldFriendly`. Имплементируем `hook_page_attachments_alter` в файле *THEMENAME.theme* используемой темы или в модуле:

```
function  THEMENAME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
    $unneeded_meta = ['HandheldFriendly', 'MobileOptimized', 'system_meta_generator'];
    foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $id => $attachment) {
        if (in_array($attachment[1], $unneeded_meta)) {
            unset($attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$id]);
        }
    }
}
```

В качестве примера изменения мета-тегов рассмотрим модификацию `viewport`. *Drupal 8* изначально выводит `viewport` так:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Его нужно изменить на такой вариант:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Соответственно изменяем его в `hook_page_attachments_alter` в *THEMENAME.theme*:

```
function THEMENAME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
    $viewport = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'viewport',
            'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
        ),
    );
    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
}
```

[Оригинал статьи](http://drup.by/snippets/drupal-8-udalenie-i-izmenenie-metategov).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Увидел в ответе копипаст своей статьи и могу сказать, что в ней рассматривается как удаление, так и изменение мета-тегов, а в вопросе было только про удаление, поэтому все было не обязательно копировать.